# query saved mqtt messages in database between start and end row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a program that directly saves my MQTT messages into a mySQL database.
I save the payload, topic and create time.
I have different topics that follow a certain sequence.

I have 'topic:start, topic:phase1 with payload:A, topic:phase2 with payload:B and topic:stop'. In between I have a lot of messages with a constant feed of temperature data.

I looks like this:

```
| Topic          | Payload | Create_time           |
| 'start'        |         | '2016-05-17 10:00:00' |
| 'temperature'  | 5       | '2016-05-17 10:00:20' |
| 'temperature'  | 6       | '2016-05-17 10:01:20' |
| 'temperature'  | 6       | '2016-05-17 10:02:20' |
| 'temperature'  | 7       | '2016-05-17 10:03:20' |
| 'temperature'  | 8       | '2016-05-17 10:04:20' |
| 'phase1'       | 'A'     | '2016-05-17 10:04:30' |
| 'temperature'  | 8       | '2016-05-17 10:05:20' |
| 'temperature'  | 9       | '2016-05-17 10:06:20' |
| 'temperature'  | 10      | '2016-05-17 10:07:20' |
| 'phase2'       | 'B'     | '2016-05-17 10:08:30' |
| 'temperature'  | 10      | '2016-05-17 10:08:50' |
| 'stop'         |         | '2016-05-17 10:08:30' |
... more sequences like this where A and B are sequence specific
```

Now I want to query this data to get it into this format:

```
 | Date         | Phase1 | Start sequence        | End sequence          | Phase2 |
 | '2016-05-17' | 'A'    | '2016-05-17 10:00:00' | '2016-05-17 10:08:30' | 'B'    |
 ...
 for every sequence where 
     - date is the date of that sequence (without time).
     - the var A of that sequence
     - the start create_time of that sequence
     - the end create_time of that sequence
     - the var B of that sequence.
```

How do I group different rows into sequences, with the variables that show up as payload between the start and end times?

Comment: I assume the sequence intervals do not overlap? else there's no way to know if `phase1` in an overlap belongs to one sequence or another

Comment: @Fabricator there is no overlap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [user defined variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) to tag the sequence (by incrementing whenever you see `Topic='start'`):

```
select date(min(Create_time)) `Date`, group_concat(if(Topic='phase1',Payload,null)) Phase1, 
  min(Create_time) `Start sequence`, 
  group_concat(if(Topic='stop',Create_time,null)) `End sequence`, 
  group_concat(if(Topic='phase2',Payload,null)) Phase2
from (
  select if(Topic='start',@id:=@id+1,@id) id, a.*
  from (
    select *
    from Table1
    order by Create_time) a
  join (select @id:=0) b) a
group by id;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bd53/6)

Comment: How can I let the 'End sequence' be th create_time of the row with the 'stop' payload? Now it is equals to the next 'start' create_time.

Comment: @KenVernaillen, right. i missed that stop time might not be the latest timestamp. in this case, you can use `group_concat(if(Topic='stop',Create_time,null))` to get that timestamp